# Add spintax ( spinning syntax ) support for textarea or emojiarea

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have installed a PHP script (grameasy) on my website for sending direct messages to instagram followers but my problem is when I write text in spintax format, it does not work, for example,

```
{hello|hi|hey} Friend
```

must be sent randomly as

```
hello Friend "or" hi Friend "or" hey Friend
```

but sent as

```
{hello|hi|hey} Friend
```

So how can I add spintax support for textarea?

Thanks.

Comment: This needs code to work. Have you tried anything?

Comment: no i don't try any code , i search so much but i could not find solution

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is what u searching for..

```
class Spintax
{
    public function process($text)
    {
        return preg_replace_callback(
            '/\{(((?>[^\{\}]+)|(?R))*)\}/x',
            array($this, 'replace'),
            $text
        );
    }

    public function replace($text)
    {
        $text = $this->process($text[1]);
        $parts = explode('|', $text);
        return $parts[array_rand($parts)];
    }
}


$spintax = new Spintax();
$string = '{hello|hi|hey} Friend';
echo $spintax->process($string);
```